# Visual Studio complains about few arguments to VirtualAlloc despite correct arguments

Tags: c, windows, winapi, dynamic-memory-allocation

I've been trying to learn my way through the winapi in C, and I'm trying to use the `VirtualAlloc()` function to allocate memory. The function clearly takes 4 arguments and I'm supplying 4 arguments as per the windows API documentation.

Function body:

```c
VirtualAlloc(
  lpAddress,
  dwSize,
  flAllocationType,
  flProtect
);
```

How I'm supplying the function:

```c
//values I inserted here have the correct types, again the problem is that it complains about few arguments
void* memory = VirtualAlloc(
        NULL,
        DRAWING_AREA_MEMORY_SIZE,
        MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT,
        PAGE_READWRITE
);
```

I tried using only one allocation type instead of piping, just in case that caused the problem for some reason, but to no avail
Error Copied from the compiler:

`Error (active)   E0165   too few arguments in function call`

I can't tell what could be the problem. Funny enough, no matter how many other arguments I throw in, it stays too few and never changes to too many. What is going on here?

Comment: What's going on here is that the shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. And until you [edit] your question and fix that, at most you can expect to get is random guesses as to what the problem is.

Comment: Seems to me that that error message also continues with "expected XX got YY", os something similar.

Comment: `Ennnn` are IntelliSense errors, and there are lots of ways to get IntelliSense confused. Ask the compiler instead (its errors are reported as `Cnnnn`).

Comment: Tried your example and it compiles fine.  Suggest r-clicking on "VirtualAlloc" in the code and "Go To Declaration" to make sure it's using the VirtualAlloc you expect.

Comment: @PeteBecker It does not, aside from what I already copied, there was only the directory path.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'll see if I can create a reproducible example quickly, thanks for mentioning.

Comment: @ChrisKushnir It does, I did check, goes to the memoryapi.h definition, intellisense even gives me a preview of the arguments I need to supply, weirdly enough.

Comment: Is DRAWING_AREA_MEMORY_SIZE a macro ?

Comment: @ChrisKushnir It is was not, but it was indeed the problem. Apparently I had an extra parenthesis that I didn't need in there(was just doing a calculation that involved parenthesis for order of operations). The compiler error did show that there was a parenthesis missing and I see it now. Thank you for reminding me to check it, works fine now!

Comment: @IInspectable the compiler error showed that there was a parenthesis missing which eventually led me to the solution, so thank you as well, Don't know why I never thought to try compiling to see the proper error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was an extra parenthesis in the DRAWING_AREA_MEMORY_SIZE  macro. Thanks to @ChrisKushnir and @IInspectable for leading me to the solution